# Efficient Sampling of A (Countable) Discrete Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a sequence of positive terms $(a_n)$, for which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = A <\infty$, and wish to take a psuedo-random sample from the discrete probability distribution

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{P}[ X = n] = \frac{a_n}{A}.
\end{equation}

The standard approach to sampling $X$ is to first sample a (continuous) uniform variable $U \sim \text{Unif}[0,1]$, and then set $X = x_U$, with 
\begin{equation}
x_U = \min \Bigg\{n \, \colon \, \sum_{k=1}^n a_k > U \Bigg\}.
\end{equation}

In general if the $a_n$ are arranged in decreasing order of magnitude, then for typical samples of $U$, $x_U$ can be calculated rather quickly. However, given that I want to sample the distribution many times, inevitably I will encounter cases where computing $x_U$ is very time consuming.

I am looking for an efficient implementation of this algorithm in Mathematica. My guess is that there is perhaps a way to do this with recursive functions, saving the totals of the 'large sums' (i.e. those over many $k$) to be used for future calculations.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Thanks!

**EDIT**
To give an example of a distirbution, consider $a_n = \log(n)/n^{(3/2)}$. This sequence is decreasing, and the associated series converges to `-Zeta'[3/2]`, i.e. $A \approx 3.93224$.

On my (admittedly not particularly swift) computer, if I sample $U =0.9$, it takes approximately 1.25 seconds to return $X =2496$. My simple (naive) implementation is as follows:

```
X[u_] := Module[{A = -Zeta'[3/2]},

k=0;
sumk=0;

While[(sumk/Z < u),
k+=1;
sumk += N[Log[k]/k^(3/2)];
];

k];
```

Comment: You can get a small speed up by premultiplying by A and removing that from the test in the loop. A significant speed up can be gained by compilation. However, the given distribution has a very heavy tail and so it is tricky to be fast for large quantiles without some adaptive sampling which is also tricky since the distribution involves Zeta functions that can't be compiled.

Comment: Thanks for your comments/interest. As a side note, the example above is not the distribution I am actually working with (no real point in providing the given distribution as it is very context specific and not particularly instructive), however at least on my computer the computation times are in fact worse than the example I give above!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are willing to precompute some things, it can be pretty quick. Here we precalculate 100000 terms of the $a_n$ sequence. Then calculate the CDF (cumulative distribution function) by using `Accumulate`. To find the closest term to the `u`, use a `NearestFunction`.

```
capA = -Zeta'[3/2] // N;
aAll = (Log[#]/#^1.5 & /@ Range[100000])/capA;
accAll = Accumulate[aAll];
nf = Nearest[accAll -> Range[Length[accAll]]];
```

To find the first time the sum is near 0.9, calculate nf[0.9]. Successive values can be done without recomputing the nearest function, so they should be very fast.

Comment: Unfortunately 100k terms doesn't even reach the 99th percentile which is where things really slow down. Heavy tails are a pain.

Comment: Well then do a million. It still runs quickly, and the complicated part (the construction of the nearest function) only occurs once.

Comment: This solution certainly runs a lot faster than my previous approach: as you say bill s, precomputing the first million (or more) values is still time efficient. As per the comment to my original post (see above), this is not the exact distribution I am interested in, however this change in my code has made it significantly easier to run simulations. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty tricky due to the very heavy tail of the distribution. You can certainly get big speed ups as suggested by bill s by pre-computing some quantiles. However, there will always be a good chunk of the tail left to compute.  I'm going to try to address the latter and borrow from Bill's solution for pre-computation.

```
s[n_] := Log[n]*n^(-1.5);    
A = Evaluate@Sum[s[k], {k, 1, Infinity}];
```

Since Mathematica can compute this sum in closed form we can use it in computing tail probabilities.

```
F[n_] := Evaluate[Sum[s[k], {k, 1, n}]]
```

This code effectively uses the derivative of the CDF to adaptively step to the next term. When the cdf is very flat and we are still a good distance from the desired quantile it steps quite far which avoids unnecessary sums. The algorithm converges when it can no longer take an integer step.

```
f[k_, q_] := If[#2 == #1, 0, Ceiling[(A*q - #1)/(#2 - #1)]] &[F[k], F[k + 1]]

tail[q_] :=
 Block[{k = 1., step},
  While[(step = f[k,q]) > 0, 
   k += step];
  k - 1
  ]
```

Now to wrap it up with the precomputed body. Note that I am using `Interpolation` rather than `Nearest`. This is because `Nearest` will be looking at closest point by Euclidean distance which isn't what we want. A little trickery with signs is necessary to get the right continuity on the zero-order interpolation.

```
maxTerms = 10^6;
x = Range[maxTerms];
y = Accumulate[s[x]/A];

ifun = Interpolation[Transpose[{-y, x}], InterpolationOrder -> 0];

c = F[maxTerms]/A;

Clear[invF];
SetAttributes[invF, Listable];
invF[q_ /; q <= c] := ifun[-q]
invF[q_/; q > c] := tail[q]
```

Now we generate some random uniforms and plot the result against the density for your distribution.

```
u = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10000];   
rvs = invF[u];

Show[Histogram[rvs, {Range[0, 100, 1]~Join~{Max[rvs]}}, "PDF"], 
 DiscretePlot[s[k]/A, {k, 1, 200}], PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, All}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy Ross: I'll have a look into your ideas here. Very helpful.